# print only filenames which contain number

Tags: r

I have several files where I want to use number present in these filenames as sample id and match all files which contain a specific number. Here's the code which I am trying.

```
underscore <- "_0.005"
sampleid_underscored <- gsub(" ", "", paste(sample_id, underscore))
pattern <- paste0("(S", sample_id, "\\.)", "|", sampleid_underscored)
matching_files <- summaryvcffiles[grepl(pattern, summaryvcffiles)]
```

When i use sample ID of 1 from command line it prints all files with 11_, 21_, 31_. I only want files with 1_ and S1 to be printed. Same goes for sample id 2.

For the files below:

```
c("./protocol12/1_0.005_consensus.vardict.summary.tab", 
  "./protocol12/11_0.005_consensus.vardict.summary.tab", 
"./protocol12/21_0.005_consensus.vardict.summary.tab", 
"./protocol12/31_0.005_consensus.vardict.summary.tab", 
"./protocol12/twiceSort/1_0.005_consensus.vardict.summary.tab", 
"./protocol12/twiceSort/11_0.005_consensus.vardict.summary.tab", 
"./protocol12/twiceSort/21_0.005_consensus.vardict.summary.tab", 
"./protocol12/twiceSort/31_0.005_consensus.vardict.summary.tab", 
"./test_S1.vardict.summary.tab", 
"./fwd-protocol12/1_0.005_consensus.vardict.summary.tab", 
"./fwd-protocol12/11_0.005_consensus.vardict.summary.tab",
"./fwd-protocol12/21_0.005_consensus.vardict.summary.tab", 
"./fwd-protocol12/31_0.005_consensus.vardict.summary.tab", 
"./fwd-protocol12/twiceSort/1_0.005_consensus.vardict.summary.tab", 
"./fwd-protocol12/twiceSort/11_0.005_consensus.vardict.summary.tab", 
"./fwd-protocol12/twiceSort/21_0.005_consensus.vardict.summary.tab", 
"./fwd-protocol12/twiceSort/31_0.005_consensus.vardict.summary.tab", 
"./rev-protocol12/1_0.005_consensus.vardict.summary.tab",
"./rev-protocol12/11_0.005_consensus.vardict.summary.tab", 
"./rev-protocol12/21_0.005_consensus.vardict.summary.tab", 
"./rev-protocol12/31_0.005_consensus.vardict.summary.tab", 
"./rev-protocol12/twiceSort/1_0.005_consensus.vardict.summary.tab", 
"./rev-protocol12/twiceSort/11_0.005_consensus.vardict.summary.tab", 
"./rev-protocol12/twiceSort/21_0.005_consensus.vardict.summary.tab", 
"./rev-protocol12/twiceSort/31_0.005_consensus.vardict.summary.tab")
```

I only want to get the files below:

```
 **"./protocol12/1_0.005_consensus.vardict.summary.tab"**
 **"./protocol12/twiceSort/1_0.005_consensus.vardict.summary.tab"**
 **"./test_S1.vardict.summary.tab"**
 **"./fwd-protocol12/1_0.005_consensus.vardict.summary.tab"**
 **"./fwd-protocol12/twiceSort/1_0.005_consensus.vardict.summary.tab"**
 **"./rev-protocol12/1_0.005_consensus.vardict.summary.tab"**
 **"./rev-protocol12/twiceSort/1_0.005_consensus.vardict.summary.tab"**
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code should work

```
path[str_detect(path, regex("(.+\\/\[your digit id here]\\_\\d+\\.\\d+)|(.+_S[your digit id here]\\.)", ignore_case = TRUE))]
```

note: be aware of regex pattern. If, in the future your pattern will be a little bit different, please try a look at [regex101](https://regex101.com/) to check your pattern. Don't forget to add an extra "\" for escaping in regexp function.

Comment: I wish to include 1 as variable stored in sample_id. Also this again prints all filenames

Comment: that's easy, you can use path[str_detect(path, regex("(.+\\/1\\_\\d+\\.\\d+)|(.+_S1\\.)", ignore_case = TRUE))]

Comment: you can change the "\d" to whatever number you want!

Comment: I edited my response so you can insert any ID you want

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
underscore <- "_0.005"

list.files(path = '.',
           pattern = sprintf("/S?1%s.*tab", underscore),
           recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE
           )
```

Answer (score 0):

This commands worked

```
pattern_to_extract <- paste0("(S", sample_id, "\\.", "|" ,"\\/", sample_id, "_0\\.005)")
matching_files <- summaryvcffiles[grepl(pattern_to_extract, summaryvcffiles)]
```